# Can't pass aps parameter in body request of payload FCM?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

[click here to check postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbOxs.png)

While migrating GCM to FCM I was using aps parameter in request body of GCM request body but when trying  same for FCM its showing InvalidParameters.

Url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Request:

```
{
 "notification": {
  "title": "notification title",
  "body": "message body changed  11"
 },
 "data": {
  "mt": "re",
  "offerid": "10562",
  "aps":{"badge":0,"alert":"gauravtest,$20 OFF COUPON","sound":"null.caf"},
  "clpnid": "xxx",
  "custid": "xxx",
  "eoid": "0",
  "pc": "171-2802-8180",
  "ed": "11/08/2017",
  "ag": "",
  "url": "",
  "previewimage": ""


 },
 "to": "xxxx"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6282546760147817634,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidParameters"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You cant send aps because the restriction is every value has to be a String, aps is an object

Cant find the doc now

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `aps` paramater isn't allowed while combining the `data` object with a `notification` object.

If you remove the `notification` object the message will be sent successfully, but you'll be sending a [data push message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) instead of a notification push message.

Answer (score 0):

//Simple its very easy use this and you have receive push and can use the extra parameters

```
"notification": {
  "title": "notification title",
  "body": "message body changed  11"
  "content_available": true,
  "extraParameter_1": "any kind of data ",
  "extraParameter_2": "any kind of data 2"
}
```